# Code igniter Shopping cart displays only one item

Tags: codeigniter

Am using Code Igniter's shopping cart. Anytime i add a new item to the cart, and show the cart items, i only see the last added item the previous items no longer exist in the cart.

```
function cart(){
    $this->load->model('products');
    if($this->uri->segment(3) =="add"){
        $item_id = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $item = $this->products->fetch_product_id($item_id);

    $data = array(
           'id'      => $item->product_id,
           'qty'     => 1,
           'price'   => $item->retail_price,
           'name'    => $item->name,
        );

        $this->cart->insert($data); 
    }
    if($this->uri->segment(3) =="update"){
    }
    $data['categories'] = $this->products->fetch_categories();
    $this->load->view('site',$data);        
}
```

What could be wrong with my code?

Comment: i realised where the problem was coming from. I was using a database for my session i.e $config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE; but i changed it to false and its working now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->load->view('site', $data)
```

Here is where your problem is at. Your $data variable contains only the last product.

You'll need to use cart_contents function to list all your products.

[Check the Displaying the Cart section](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html)